# How to customize DB Manager default parameters

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I'm using QGIS 2.10 and DB Manager plugin.

I regularly use this plugin to display tables from a PostgreSQL - PostGIS database. I particularly use the integrated SQL Window to filter a table's content with a SQL query. Then, in order to display the query's result in the QGIS map canvas, it is asked to specify `Column with unique integer value` and `Geometry column` (see screenshot below). These parameters are automatically filled with a column name and I have to change the values to `gid` and `the_geom` each time I use this...

Is there a way to specify default values for these parameters, as `gid` and `the_geom` are always the columns to be used for every table in my database?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tried QGIS 2.14.4 and DB Manager seems to keep in memory last field names selected for *Column with unique values* and *Geometry column* parameters!

The solution is simple then: **upgrade!**